# How to install ReactiveCocoa properly using CocoaPods?

Tags: ios, cocoapods, reactive-cocoa

I'm very new to `ReactiveCocoa`. I tried to install `ReactiveCocoa` a couple of days ago via `CocoaPods`. 
Here is my `podFile`:

```
platform :ios , '7.0'
pod 'ReactiveCocoa'
```

After using `pod install` I have the log file here:

> Analyzing dependencies
>
> Downloading dependencies
>
> Using ReactiveCocoa (2.0)
>
> Generating Pods project
>
> Integrating client project

And then I open `myproject.xworkspace` and `#import <ReactiveCocoa.h>` to start using the framework.
**But the problem is I cannot get it worked**

For example in my code I have this line:
`objc
RACSignal *usernameSignal = self._usernameTextField.rac_textSignal;`

But when I run the project, it showed up this debug error

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITextField rac_textSignal]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb933a70'

I believed that I might do something wrong with the framework installation here. Anyone please help me out!

I'm using `XCode5 and iOS7.0`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out the issues. It's because CocoaPods doesn't add the flag `-all_load` in my project build setting. After setting it manually, it works like a charm.
Hope this help everyone who experience the same issue like me

Comment: Can you modify the ReactiveCocoa pod to do this automatically? Is this a new requirement?

Comment: @allprog, I don't know if it's requirement. Currently I'm using `ReactiveCocoa 2.1` set up by `CocoaPods`. You could check the configuration in `Pods.xcconfig` file. Look at this line: `OTHER_LDFLAGS = ...`, mine only have `-ObjC` flags, so I added `-all_load` flag to make sure I can use all resources from `ReactiveCocoa`. Remember to add `$(inherited)` flag to your `other linker flag` at your project build setting.

Comment: I'm one of the maintainers of the ReactiveCocoa pod spec — there shouldn't be a requirement for the `-all_load` flag. It's working fine with Xcode 5.0.x, iOS 7.x and OS X 10.8/10.9. What version of CocoaPods are you using?

Comment: @TonyArnold, I was using `XCode 5` and `iOS7` and `ReactiveCocoa 2.0` for development, the fact is if I don't use `-all_load` flag, `ReactiveCocoa`acted so weirdly with `signal`. But now I can reconfirm that `ReactiveCocoa 2.1` is working flawlessly without adding `-all_load` flag.