# ReactiveCocoa unrecognized selector

Tags: ios, xcode, reactive-cocoa

I managed to successfully integrate `ReactiveCocoa` via `CocoaPods`.

The project also builds and runs.

In a file I have this code:

```
#import <ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa.h>
#import <ReactiveCocoa/UITextField+RACSignalSupport.h>

UITextField *fld = [UITextField new];
[fld.rac_textSignal subscribeNext:^(id x)
{
    NSLog(@"___%@___", x);
}];
```

When I run it it generates the error:

```
-[UITextField rac_textSignal]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd2fa6cda50'
```

I already tried the solution proposed here: [How to install ReactiveCocoa properly using CocoaPods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19118913/how-to-install-reactivecocoa-properly-using-cocoapods)
but without any success.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to integrate CocoaPods with an existing project, then you should  add an `$(inherited)` flag to `Other Linker flags` at the build settings.

Comment: Wasn't exactly this one, but another linker flag. Thx anyway!

Comment: Whhhyyyy wouldn't you write which one it was? :)